# How to compare AtomicBoolean with boolean value in java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, atomicboolean

I'm trying to deploy TTAS in a multi-threading application in java, using this code:

```
AtomicBoolean state= new AtomicBoolean(false);
void lock(){
    while(true)
    {
      while(state.get())
      {
        if(!state.getAndSet(true))
        return;
      }
    }
}
```

but how can I compare the value of the state to check if it's true or false, when I try to spin on the it's value while I got each time an error saying that I'm trying to compare two different variables' type ? 
exp:

```
Lock lock = new Lock();
if(lock.state==true) // error ! 
{
   //do something
}
```

thank you!

Comment: isn't AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet what you need?

Comment: @user1121883, yeah! that's right! this is what I should use! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but how can I compare the value of the state to check if it's true or false

You just need to call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#get%28%29):

```
if (lock.state.get())
```

I'm confused as to why you didn't see this before though, given that you're already using it in your `while` loop:

```
while(state.get())
```

Comment: this is what happen when you don't sleep for 48 h :)
@Jon Skeet

Comment: why i didn't think of that ... :) .. Thanks @jon-skeet